# Leaflet Shpjs shapefile does not appear in Chrome

Tags: shapefile, leaflet, chrome, firefox

I'm using the package **shpjs** with **Leaflet** to import shapefiles and show them on the map. It works perfectly on **Firefox Mozilla**, but not for some shapefiles in **Chrome**.

This is my code:

```
 var shpfile = new L.Shapefile(couche, {
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
          if (feature.properties) {
            layer.bindPopup(
              Object.keys(feature.properties)
                .map(function (k) {
                  if (k === "__color__") {
                    return;
                  }
                  console.log("=========>", feature);
                  return k + ": " + feature.properties[k];
                })
                .join("<br />"),
              {
                maxHeight: 200
              }
            );
          }
        },
        style: function (feature) {
          return {
            opacity: 1,
            fillOpacity: 0.7,
            radius: 6,
            color: "tomato"
          };
        },
        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
          return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
            opacity: 1,
            fillOpacity: 0.7,
            color: feature.properties.__color__
          });
        }
      });
      shpfile.addTo(m);
      shpfile.once("data:loaded", function () {
        console.log("finished loaded shapefile");
      });

      var baseLayers = {
        "OSM Mapnik": osmMap,
        "Carto DarkMatter": cartoMap,
        "Stamen Toner": stamenMap
      };

      //Add baseLayers to map as control layers
      L.control.layers(baseLayers).addTo(m);
```

This is a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/shp-leaflet-b4z5d?file=/index.html) where shp a1.zip appears in Firefox but not in Chrome, but a2.zip appears in both of them. I think it's relative to Z and M values in the shapefile.

Comment: @TomazicM i puted a demo in codesandbox

Comment: Yeah i'm sorry i deleted that line that was not the real problem,

Comment: But im still uploading the shapefile a1.zip "exemple in sandbox" it appears in firefox but not in chrome without showing an error message

Comment: Once again: question was about "statesData is not defined" error. Are you still getting this error?

Comment: no i dont have any error now i deleted that line

Comment: but the same issue the shapefile not appear

Answer (score 4):

After finding out that both `a1.zip` and `a2.zip` shapefiles work OK in all browsers on `Leaflet.shpfile` plugin demo page http://leaflet.calvinmetcalf.com/#3/32.69/10.55, it was just a matter of finding out what components this page is using that make it work.

It turned out that culprit is `shp.js` library. If this library is taken from page http://leaflet.calvinmetcalf.com/jam/shp/dist/shp.js, then the above code from question will work.