# Remove M value & Z value from shapefile JavaScript

Tags: shapefile, leaflet, javascript, z-value, m-values

Is there a way to remove the *m value* and the *z value* from a shapefile using JavaScript "**leafletjs & shpjs**”?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by removing those values?

Comment: I have 2 shapefiles 1st one M value and Z value are checked in arcmap and the 2nd one they are not checked, for the 1st it does not appear with leaflet but the 2nd appear, so im searching for a way to remove those values from the shp

Comment: Shapefiles have 2-4 values per vertex -- X and Y are mandatory; the Z and M are optional, but only optional for the entire shapefile. You would need to completely rewrite the shapefile to remove Z and/or M dimensions (this cannot be done *in-situ* in most interfaces).

Comment: Using just the packages you mentioned? I don't think so. Neither seem to **write** to shape. You'll most likely need to convert from shp to GeoJSON, and then parse the GeoJSON (drop z's), and write to a new "z-not-enabled shapefile". But you'll need a package that writes to SHP. A quick search finds: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62544929/leaflet-shp-write-to-convert-geojson-to-shapefile (with good links in the unanswered question)

Comment: You won't need to do this. See my answer to your question that is reason for this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/401426/leaflet-shpjs-shpfile-does-not-appear